# Right way to equalize mp3 file in python

Tags: python, audio, mp3, mutagen

I'm currently working on a little python script to equalize MP3 file. 
I've read some docs about MP3 file format (at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ID3) 
And i've noticed that in the ID3v2 format there is a field for Equalization (EQUA, EQU2)
Using the python librarie mutagen i've tried to extract theses information from the MP3 but the field isn't present.
What's the right way to equalize MP3 file regardless of the ID3 version ? 
Thank in advance. Creekorful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two high-level approaches you can take: modify the encoded audio stream, or put metadata on it describing the desired change. Modifying the audio stream is the most compatible, but generally less desirable. However, ID3v1 has no place for this metadata, only ID3v2.2 and up do.

Depending on what you mean by equalize, you might want equalization information stored in the EQA/EQUA/[EQU2](https://github.com/quodlibet/mutagen/blob/master/mutagen/id3/_frames.py#L1181) frames, or a replay gain volume adjustment stored in the [RVA](https://github.com/quodlibet/mutagen/blob/master/mutagen/id3/_frames.py#L2016)/[RVAD](https://github.com/quodlibet/mutagen/blob/master/mutagen/id3/_frames.py#L1206)/[RVA2](https://github.com/quodlibet/mutagen/blob/master/mutagen/id3/_frames.py#L1132) frames. Mutagen supports the linked frames, so all but EQA/EQUA. If you need them, it should be straightforward to add them from the information in the actual specification (see 4.12 on http://id3.org/id3v2.4.0-frames). With tests they could likely be contributed back to the project.

Note that Quod Libet, the player paired with Mutagen, has taken a preference for [reading and storing replay gain information](https://github.com/quodlibet/quodlibet/blob/master/quodlibet/quodlibet/formats/_id3.py#L213) in a [TXXX](https://github.com/quodlibet/mutagen/blob/master/mutagen/id3/_frames.py#L861) frame.